# Running the app in AVD without opening the Eclipse

Tags: android

I hav created Calcy app in Eclipse. It is running in Emulator properly.

But i want to run it using  AVD manager .

the command for installing the app is "adb install Calcy.apk"

but it is giving the message that

```
C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb install Calcy.apk
252 KB/s (39547 bytes in 0.153s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/Calcy.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
```

How to resolve this...

Comment: Please accept Answer so other people may helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Please first remove this app from Emulator then run **"adb install Calcy.apk"**

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to uninstall first using `adb uninstall your.package.name`, then try `adb install -r Calcy.apk`

Answer (score 0):

**Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]**

this means the app already installed in the emulator. You can go into Application manager tool and uninstall app from emulator. then again run this command and you will be able to install it.

*You need to uninstall the already installed app. then this command will work*

you can also remove app with below command

```
adb uninstall package_name
```